# VBS singleselectnode looping

Tags: vb.net, loops, vbscript

what is the correct way to do SelectSingleNode for the below xml where I want the percentile value for p50, p90, p95 and p99. I also have many of them so I am looping them but I am getting only the first one

```
<Measure>
      <Class>Timer</Class>
      <Name>EMF-01-Launch</Name>
      <Type>Response time[s]</Type>
      <Unit>Seconds</Unit>
      <Timebound1>0.000000000</Timebound1>
      <Timebound2>0.000000000</Timebound2>
      <IDMeasureType>3</IDMeasureType>
      <IDMeasureClass>2</IDMeasureClass>
      <TypeDisplayStr>Response time[s]</TypeDisplayStr>
      <SumCount1>34778.000000000</SumCount1>
      <SumCount2>20619.000000000</SumCount2>
      <SumSum>2885.826000000</SumSum>
      <SumSqSum>1084.245452000</SumSqSum>
      <MinMin>0.031000000</MinMin>
      <MaxMax>5.866000000</MaxMax>
      <Avg>0.139959552</Avg>
      <Stdd>0.181648280</Stdd>
      <SumTimeboundCount1>
        <Percent>0.000000000</Percent>
        0
      </SumTimeboundCount1>
      <SumTimeboundCount2>
        <Percent>0.000000000</Percent>
        0
      </SumTimeboundCount2>
      <SortNo>0</SortNo>
      <Percentiles>
        <ID>0</ID>
        <Values>
          <Value>
            <Percent>50</Percent>
            <Value>0.109000000</Value>
          </Value>
          <Value>
            <Percent>90</Percent>
            <Value>0.235000000</Value>
          </Value>
          <Value>
            <Percent>95</Percent>
            <Value>0.314000000</Value>
          </Value>
          <Value>
            <Percent>99</Percent>
            <Value>0.784000000</Value>
          </Value>
        </Values>
      </Percentiles>

For Each SNode in scriptNodes
scriptName = SNode.SelectSingleNode("Name").text
'For each measure of type Timer

Set timerNodes = SNode.selectNodes("Measures/Measure")
'msgbox (timerNodes.length)
For Each TNode in timerNodes

If TNode.SelectSingleNode("Class").text = "Timer" then
' Extract the timer data

timerName = TNode.SelectSingleNode("Name").text
min = TNode.SelectSingleNode("MinMin").text
avg = TNode.SelectSingleNode("Avg").text
max = TNode.SelectSingleNode("MaxMax").text
stDev = TNode.SelectSingleNode("Stdd").text
count = TNode.SelectSingleNode("SumCount2").text
p50 = TNode.SelectSingleNode("Percentiles/Values/Value[1]/Value").text
msgbox (p50)
p90 = TNode.SelectSingleNode("//Percentiles/Values/Value[2]/Value").text
p95 = TNode.SelectSingleNode("//Percentiles/Values/Value[3]/Value").text
p99 = TNode.SelectSingleNode("//Percentiles/Values/Value[4]/Value").text

'Write to File
fileHandle.WriteLine(scriptName+","+timerName+","+min+","+avg+","+max+","+stDev+","+count+","+p50+","+p90+","+p95+","+p99)
end if

Next 'TNode in timerNodes
Next 'SNode in scriptNodes
fileHandle.Close
```

Comment: I am getting only the data for only the first loop and for the next its repeating the first loop elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the 'drill down' in a systematic way, identify the spots in your code where you can/must collect information, and don't forget `selectNodes()`. Demo code to help your experiments:

```
  Dim sFSpec   : sFSpec       = goFS.GetAbsolutePathName("..\testdata\xml\22955875.xml")
  Dim objMSXML : Set objMSXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
  objMSXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
  objMSXML.async = False
  objMSXML.load sFSpec

  If 0 = objMSXML.parseError Then
     WScript.Echo "ok"
     Dim dicData : Set dicData = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
     dicData("MinMin") = ""
     dicData("MaxMax") = ""
     Dim TNode : Set TNode = objMSXML.SelectSingleNode("/Measure") ' fake for fragment
     If TNode Is Nothing Then
        WScript.Echo "no TNode"
     Else
        Dim sKey, ndFnd, ndlFnd, aPX, i
        For Each sKey In dicData.Keys
            Set ndFnd = TNode.selectSingleNode(sKey)
            If ndFnd Is Nothing Then
               WScript.Echo sKey, "not found"
            Else
               dicData(sKey) = ndFnd.text
            End If
        Next
        Set ndlFnd = TNode.selectNodes("Percentiles/Values/Value")
        If 0 = ndlFnd.length Then
           WScript.Echo "no values"
        Else
           ReDim aPX(ndlFnd.length - 1)
           For i = 0 To UBound(aPX)
               aPX(i) = "??"
               Set ndFnd = ndlFnd(i).selectSingleNode("Value")
               If ndFnd Is Nothing Then
                  WScript.Echo "no value"
               Else
                  aPX(i) = ndFnd.text
               End If
           Next
           dicData("px") = "[" & Join(aPX, ",") & "]"
        End If
        For Each sKey In dicData.Keys()
            WScript.Echo sKey, "=>", dicData(sKey)
        Next
        WScript.Echo Join(dicData.Items(), ",")
     End If
  Else
     WScript.Echo objMSXML.parseError.reason
  End If
```

outut:

```
ok
MinMin => 0.031000000
MaxMax => 5.866000000
px => [0.109000000,0.235000000,0.314000000,0.784000000]
0.031000000,5.866000000,[0.109000000,0.235000000,0.314000000,0.784000000]
```